# Web Crawler for a Domain and all Subsites

Tags: web-crawler

I am trying to extract all my domain subsites and add them to an excel sheet. So far all of the web crawlers I have used only report url's from the crawl foundation page. I was wondering if there is a way to report url's that are not reachable from the foundation page and if not what are some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Crawlers are generally used for visiting many websites and their pages. If you want a list of the web adresses of the pages in a single domain you don't need to use a web crawler. 
Keep a list of links that are outgoing from the homepage. Check if they belong to the same domain. Iterate through the list visiting each page and redo the check every time until you consume the whole domain. Remember that without any links to a specific page in the same domain, the page is inaccesible.

Comment: It's irregular if a page is accessible from some other domain and not from the same domain.